# Connecting a Slack webhook to GitHub

Tags: github, webhooks, slack

First of all, I'm not sure if this is the place to post this, but this is my last stop to get this fixed.

I've been trying to connect a Slack WebHook with a GitHub repository and I fail every time.

The steps I followed:

1. Create a webhook (both individually and using a new slack app) Copy
2. Copy the hook URL and paste in the new hook option in the GitHub repo.
3. Then when I create it, it gives me an error.

BTW, what should I add to the "Secret" field?

Please check the screenshot for more info.

[image: Creating the hook]

Then I get the below error.

[image: Error]

Let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Looks to me that github uses its own format for the payload, which can not be configured and does not match Slack's format. Which I guess is why you get the error. But why do you not use the free Github Slack app instead?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the GitHub app and it didn't work. That's why I tried this option. Then after your response, I realized that I use GitHub Enterprise version and it doesn't support the GitHub app. There is a different version named GitHub Notifications (Legacy), and only that works for the enterprise version. The term "legacy" had misled me not to use it. Anyway, I got my requirement done using that app. Thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: Also, there is no secret required to use the Slack webhook

Comment: This "GitHub Notifications (Legacy)" is the only thing that worked for us.

Comment: Looks like Github, left this for other tools to generate some income. Why is it so complex ? for Gitlab it's a walk over

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still valid, but as I am also trying to create this connection, I found a possible solution in the GH Marketplace: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/slack-webhook-for-github-actions